# can we use phabricator for existing svnrepo with 500gb

Tags: devops, phabricator, devops-services

Here small question,
Having 500GB svn data, can we use phabricator for this, and how to configure for that,can we clone phabricatorsvn repo for specific files like normal svn cloning using tortoise svn.

Answer (score 0):

Phabricator is able to handle large repositories without any problem. Your server should have enough space for the repositories though. Take a look at [Diffusion User Guide](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/diffusion_hosting/) (Phabricator Repo Management) for how to configure the server to host repositories.

Comment: Am trying svn  hosted repository on phabrication. I am done with all configuration.
but still asking for password.  am using oracle linux 7.5 
find visudo
#Defaults   !requiretty
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
Cmnd_Alias PG_PEG_CMNDS = ALL
PG_PEG_USERS ALL = (ppoker) NOPASSWD: PG_PEG_CMNDS
PG_PEG_USERS ALL = (gmedia) NOPASSWD: PG_PEG_CMNDS
daemon-user     ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
vcs-user ALL=(daemon-user) SETENV: NOPASSWD: ALL, /usr/sbin/sshd
apache ALL=(daemon-user) SETENV: NOPASSWD: ALL
echo {} | ssh vcs-user@in1bcmcoderev001.ivycomptech.co.in conduit conduit.ping
Password:

Comment: @kishoreravi The comments system lacks any sufficient formatting to be able to understand what's going on there. If you have a new question, ask a new separate question. If you're adding follow-up information to this same question, edit your question above.